# Rviz shows robot in a "crippled way" using MotionPlanning

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anytime I run Rviz and use Motionplanning the robot is not shown the way it should be... Right now I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6bBxfD_bYs

and as soon as I run the created launch file rviz pops up and shows me a strange representation of my ur5. It looks like every single link is connected to the base link. I had the same issue when I tried the moveit Panda Tutorial. If I only add the robot model it looks fine, but as soon as I add the MotionPlanning it gets weird. Execution from there almost never works...
[image: image description]

2 erros I see in the bash (dunno if they are responsible for the behaviour):

```
[ERROR] [1553171470.019237215, 407.916000000]: Could not find the planner configuration 'None' on the param server
[ WARN] [1553171477.355538521, 413.008000000]: Waiting for arm_contoller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ INFO] [1553171481.580805297, 416.272000000]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group? at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-moveit-ros-planning-0.10.8/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp:495
[ INFO] [1553171482.618004378, 416.826000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'manipulator' in namespace ''
[ WARN] [1553171487.914143567, 419.010000000]: Waiting for arm_contoller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1553171496.372846748, 425.010000000]: Action client not connected: arm_contoller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

I would be glad if you can explain in the easiest way, since I am new to everything (linux, Ros, C++).

Thanks,
Joel

Edit: Output locale: (sorry that it doesn't look pretty with a grey background, no idea how to paste it that way)

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319077/rviz-shows-robot-in-a-%22crippled-way%22-using-motionplanning/) by [Joel1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/40557/joel1394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joel1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/40557/joel1394/) on 2019-03-21**:
I don't know if I am getting it right. So I just copied this line now into my terminal:

export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

nothing happens. Problem remains, also after reboot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-21**:
A reboot would have reset everything to the default situation, so that would be expected.

Can you show us the output of `locale` (run it in a terminal, copy-paste the output)?

And please attach a screenshot of RViz to your question. Use the `edit` button to add it to your original question text.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-21**:
This could still be #q272692.

But first: can you show us a screenshot of `rqt_graph` when you have everything running?

And which launch files do you use?

Just adding the MoveIt RViz plugin without having the correct parameters and nodes loaded will not work.

---

As to the potential locale problem: you can test that by switching your machine to use the `en_US.UTF-8` locale globally. This will (temporarily) turn your machine to English, but you can switch that back later. To switch it, use the *Region & Language* section of the System Settings panel.

Switch it to English (US), confirm the change, save and log out and then log in.

Now try again.

**Comment by [Joel1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/40557/joel1394/) on 2019-03-22**:
Thanks! Changing the language to english (US) and afterwards executing the code I used earlier (havn't checked yet if the code is really necessary), made the robot look all pretty now. Apparently  I can plan, but now it tells me the following errors

```
[ERROR] [1553260867.318809360]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ elbow_joint shoulder_lift_joint shoulder_pan_joint wrist_1_joint wrist_2_joint wrist_3_joint ]
[ERROR] [1553260867.318866162]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ERROR] [1553260867.318920173]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I checked the files in the config data but the joints are always named as listed in the error... I am not sure if I had this error before, but I believe I didn't...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-22**:
Ok, so it was the locale issue then.

It would seem the comment by @RikTonnaer was actually correct.

I'll convert that into an answer for you to accept.

As to your new/other problem: please post a new question for that. Posting follow-up questions in comments like that is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Joel, this looks like the same problem as in #q272692. Can you try if the solution mentioned there also works for you?

---

Originally posted by [RikTonnaer](https://answers.ros.org/users/29027/riktonnaer/) with karma: 36 on 2019-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1